# Why are the conditions in if block not working correctly?

Tags: python

Yakshemash ! I am a Java programmer learning python to make throwaway scripts. I want to make a parser which is shown in the code below.

```
class Parser(object):
    def parse_message(self, message):
        size= len(message)
        if size != 3 or size != 5:
            raise ValueError("Message length is not valid.")

parser = Parser()
message = "12345"
parser.parse_message(message)
```

This code throws the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/temp/file.py", line 9, in <module>
    parser.parse_message(message)
  File "/temp/file.py", line 5, in parse_message
    raise ValueError("Message length is not valid.")
ValueError: Message length is not valid.
```

What is my mistake and how do I correct it ?

Comment: Your message has the length 5, which is different from 3, so the ValueError is raised. Did you want `if size != 3 and size != 5:` instead?

Comment: @tommy.carstensen - What is the : after 5 ? I want to reject a message if its size is not 3 or not 5. Not sure why one would use "and" to meet my needs.

Comment: See explicit/elaborate answer from @idjaw below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is with your conditional statement using `or`:

```
if size != 3 or size != 5:
```

If the size is not equal to 3 "OR" it is not equal to 5, then raise.

So, with your input being passed: `12345`

```
Is it not equal to 3? True
Is it not equal to 5? False

True or False = True

Result: Enter condition and raise
```

Instead, use `and`

```
if size != 3 and size != 5:

Is it not equal to 3? True
Is it not equal to 5? False

True and False = False

Result: Do not enter condition
```

Even better, use `not in`

```
if size not in (3, 5):
```

Answer (score 1):

Syntactically, there is nothing wrong in your code. The output is correct according to your code.

```
size != 3 or size != 5:   
# This will be always *true* because it is impossible for **message**
  to be of two different lengths at the same time to make the condition false.
```

Since the above condition always results *true*, I assume that you wanted to do something else.

Now putting an **and** logical operator works like below:

```
size != 3 and size != 5:  
# This will be true if the length of **message** is neither 3 nor 5
# This will be false if the length of **message** is either 3 or 5
```